# Unity light cookies with MRTK

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am kinda new to Hololens development, I wanted to place a spotlight, switchable by a toggle button and use a Unity light cookie on that spotlight to project a simple crosshair onto my hologram.

Now I can't get light cookies to work in my Project. I created my cookie to Unity specification, and the cookie works in a normal Unity 3D Project.

My suspicion is that, since cookies use a black/white image to define where to project light, the Hololens -where black is seen as transparant- does not work with light cookies. Is my suspicion right? Or is there a special process to get light cookies to work?
Or could the shaders be a reason?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> My suspicion is that, since cookies use a black/white image to define where to project light, the Hololens -where black is seen as transparent- does not work with light cookies. Is my suspicion right?

No, this is irrelevant. The "black/white" image is just gray-scale light cookie texture. You can change the Color of the spot light as you wish.

The Unity Light Cookies should work on HoloLens, just verified in the HoloLens emulator: Use the texture in the Standard Assets and set the Color of light as white.

Please notice that the recommended Unity version for HoloLens development is 2018.4.x, check out the official guidance: [Install the tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools#choose-your-engine)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the cookie only renders when the Spotlights Render Mode is set to important. Lets hope this does not influence too much.

[image: Unity Spotlight Render mode]